# How to add a list of classes and only show the last one in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, setattribute

I have a function that calls a random number of classes added into my divs:

```
htmlFields[i].classList.add(numbers[i]);
```

`numbers[i]` can add random classes: `'one','two','three','four','five'`

And my divs that already has `'static'`,`'static2'` classes gets random classes added like this:

```
<div class="static static2 five one">
<div class="static static2 two four one">
<div class="static static2 one three four">
<div class="static static2 five one">
<div class="static static2 one five four">
```

I want to keep the static classes and add only the last class from random classes. I tried to use `setAttribute()` method but it removed static classes.

So how can I only add the last one of the 'random classes' and keep the static classes at the same time?

Comment: Please show all the code where you attempt to add only the last random class.

Comment: You probably are looking for `addClass()` and not for `setAttribute` which change all the class elements

Comment: @luigonsec — `addClass` is a jQuery (jQuery is not being used in this question) wrapper around `classList.add` (which is used in the first code example of the question).

Comment: Thanks everybody, I used setAttribute() method and also added my static classes to it like so. 
setAttribute('class',  'static static1 ' + numbers[i]);

Answer (score 1):

In your function before you call the setAttribute, you need to store the current class in variable and add your random number class like the code below:

```
var currentClass = htmlFields[i].getAttribute('class');
currentClass += " " + numbers[i];
htmlFields[i].setAttribute('class', currentClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either explicitly remove all the other random classes, or use `setAttribute` and re-add the static classes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the "random" classes:

```
for ( var j = 0; j < numbers.length; ++j )
  // it's safe to "remove" a class that isn't actually set,
  // so we don't need to check
  htmlFields[i].classList.remove( numbers[j] );
```

Then add the one you want.

```
htmlFields[i].classList.add(numbers[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly do you mean by random classes, and by what condition you want to add one of those classes, but here is how you can add classes without loosing your static classes.

```js
var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.static')),
    numbers = ['one','two','three','four','five'];

elems.forEach(function(elem, i) {
    elem.className = elem.className + " " + numbers[i];
});
```

```html
<div class="static static2"></div>
<div class="static static2"></div>
<div class="static static2"></div>
<div class="static static2"></div>
<div class="static static2"></div>
```